# Why does webpack 5 have duplicated source maps when seen in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

While debugging my Webpack 5 based Angular app in Chrome dev tools, the same source file appears under two protocols: webpack:// and webpack-internal://.

[Screenshot from chrome debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwhqB.png)

webpack-internal seems to be transpiled output. How can I prevent it from showing up in the debugger?